# VSCode extension no longer displays folder or file icon from Material Icon theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview

I have a VSCode extension that has worked for over a year. This extension displays a TreeView and I make use of the Material Icon Theme package. I simply want to display an icon for Folders and Files - nothing particularly fancy.

My code simply contains this :

```
this.iconPath = new vscode.ThemeIcon("folder");
```

This has worked fine for well over the past year. The only change is to regular VSCode installs of new releases as they become available.

However, now the icons that are now being displayed in the tree appear to be the codicon icons for each of folder and file and not the icons from Material Icon Theme.
VSCode itself is using the Material Icons theme - but my Treeview extension is no longer displaying the Material Icons for folders and files.
I added these 2 lines to show that the Material Icon theme is active.

```
const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();
console.log(config.workbench.iconTheme); // Correctly displays => material-icon-theme
```

In the past simply specifying

```
this.iconPath = new vscode.ThemeIcon("folder");
```

was sufficient to get the the theme icon to be presented.

I have searched recent VSCode documentation to see if something has changed in this area but I find nothing.

Can anybody offer any suggestions as to what may have changed?

Comment: I don't know what has changed but does `this.iconPath = vscode.ThemeIcon.Folder` do what you want?

Comment: Hi, no changing to that makes no difference at all.   I am still presented with the codicon icons.

Comment: I have found that adding this line
`this.resourceUri = Uri.parse('_.js');`
appears to resolve the problem but it was not previously necessary over the past 12+ months.
I have no clue as to what this line accomplishes and it seems any value - even a blank value between the ( ) works.

Comment: Adding this.resourceUri =  has completely screwed up my extension and causes a lot of very strange issues. 
Can anybody advise as to how to get the icon displayed ?
this.iconPath = vscode.ThemeIcon.Folder
this.resourceUti = Uri.parse("_.js');  

That second line causes a host of problems in the Treeview  but without it no icon is provided.